Uninstalled Anaconda, and python manage.py runserver shows [Errno 2] No such file or directory
I had downloaded Anaconda then finished a food project in virtualenv (in virtualenv, I downloaded Python 3.12 and added it to Path during downloading):

But then, I uninstalled Anaconda and found I can't run the Food project now, as below:

Before that, I could run it by typing the same command, and I do have python installed:

Is it because I uninstalled Anaconda? but when I developed Foot project, I didn't open Anaconda; instead, I activated myvenv and installed all packages I need and Django by using pip install.
Is it because I installed Python in C drive and developed the project in D drive? but during my development, it used to run successfully before I uninstalled Anaconda. How can I fix the problem and have the Food project run successfully again? only reinstall Anaconda?
I would like to use python virtualenv + pip to install Django and packages I need for my future projects, and not to use Anaconda, is it possible?

I've had a problem like this before. If you go to that folder by doing "cd file" in the directory where your manage.py file is, then run the command, there will be no problem. This problem is not related to anaconda, you are in the wrong folder.
